# Technique for dynamically adding a join to a linq query?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a Linq query that sometimes is joined on two datasets and at other times is joined on three. There is never data returned from the third set it is just used to filter the data based on it's content. I use Predicate Builder for dynamically creating wheres but am not sure the right way to dynamically include/exclude a joined dataset.

Sometimes this:

```
var filteredResults = from d in dateRangeResults
                              join n in results on d.ID equals n.ID                                
                              select new { name = n, demo = d };
```

And other times I need this:

```
    var filteredResults = from d in dateRangeResults
                              join n in results on d.ID equals n.ID
                              join p in PnSIncludeResults on n.ID equals p
                              select new { name = n, demo = d };
```

Is there a best practice or technique?
TIA

Answer (score 4):

For performance I would add the extra join within an `if` statement.  This will build a single efficient query in both cases:

```
var filteredResults = from d in dateRangeResults
                      join n in results on d.ID equals n.ID
                      select new { name = n, demo = d };

if(filterExtra)
{
    filteredResults = from result in filteredResults
                      join p in PnSIncludeResults on result.name.ID equals p
                      select result;
}
```

If you're more concerned about readability, you can use a `where` clause instead of a `join` clause:

```
var filteredResults = from d in dateRangeResults
                      join n in results on d.ID equals n.ID
                      where !filterExtra || PnSIncludeResults.Contains(n.ID)
                      select new { name = n, demo = d };
```

LINQ to Entities might optimize the resulting query, but you should check to be sure.