# EF extend query per case

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following case:

I need to execute the following linq query on an EF context

```
from table1 in context.TableOne
join table2 in context.TableTwo on table1.SomeFKId equals table2.Id
join table3 in context.TableThree on table2.SomeFKId equals table3.Id
...
join tableN in context.TableN on tableN_1.SomeFKId equals tableN.Id
where case1 && case2 && case3 ... && caseN
select new TablesDto { VarOne = table1.Var , VarTwo = tableN_2.var }
```

My problem is that I want to use the same query in diffirent senarios with alot of extentions.
I would rather not write it many times (DRY principle) just extend it but not at the cost of efficiency and speed.

That is if I wanted to join the first table with another I could extend the Dto to incorporate the rest of the variables but if I were to iterate through the rows I would need a query per row to extend it. Since I am talking about 100 to 5000 rows, even the iteration would take some time.

Extentions include: Other cases (case1, case2 etc) and other joins.

Extention Example:

```
from table1 in context.TableOne
join table2 in context.TableTwo on table1.SomeFKId equals table2.Id
join table3 in context.TableThree on table2.SomeFKId equals table3.Id
...
join tableN in context.TableN on tableN_1.SomeFKId equals tableN.Id
join extTable in context.TableExt on table2.SomeFKId equals extTable.Id
where case1 && case2 && case3 ... && caseN || extTable.NumOfSmth == 4
select new ExtTablesDto { VarOne = table1.Var , VarTwo = tableN_2.var , ExtVar = extTable.Name }
```

Comment: It would help to see examples two different cases. I don't understand the second-last paragraph. I also wonder how "other joins" should be parametrized.

Comment: Is `TablesDto` always the same? I'm afraid you're trying to rub yourself so DRY it's gonna hurt.

Comment: Nope the dto changes each time. But the dto is the base class for the others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
void Main()
{
    using(var dal = new DataAccessLayer())
    {
        var items = dal.TablesDtoQuery.Case1().Case2().ToList();
    }
}

public class DataAccessLayer : IDisposable
{
    private DbContext context;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }

    public IQueryable<TablesDto> TablesDtoQuery
    {
        get
        {
            return 
                from table1 in context.TableOne
                join table2 in context.TableTwo on table1.SomeFKId equals table2.Id
                join table3 in context.TableThree on table2.SomeFKId equals table3.Id
                ...
                join tableN in context.TableN on tableN_1.SomeFKId equals tableN.Id
                where case1 && case2 && case3 ... && caseN
                select new TablesDto { VarOne = table1.Var , VarTwo = tableN_2.var };
        }
    }
}

public static class TablesDtoQueryExtension
{
    public IQueryable<TablesDto> Case1(this IQueryable<TablesDto> query)
    {
        return from t in query
            where ...
            select t;
    }

    public IQueryable<TablesDto> Case2(this IQueryable<TablesDto> query)
    {
        return from t in query
            where ...
            select t;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you mate, I followed the example with the extention methods, basic classes etc and I finally got it in a slightly variant way.

Answer (score 1):

you can extend the where query very easy like this

```
var query = from user in dbContext.Users where user.id = 10;

if (x == 3)
{
   query = query.where(p=>p.name == "test");
}
```

and so on you can extend the base Query here you will search after UserId = 10 and name = "test"

If you have an EF Model then you should try to create the dependencies between the Tables there, then you don't need to join them in your Query

Comment: I have dependencies, but I am looking for speed here that is why I project my properties to data in one query instead of many. An my design does not allow me to use eager fetching of data. This solution would also execute 2 queries instead of one. I could though use this to extend the Where clauses but not my joins.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras "execute 2 queries instead of one". Not true. `DbQuery/ObjectQuery` does not hit the database until `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` is called.

Comment: Sorry that is true. You are right, it still does not solve the join problem.

Comment: hello perhaps this Helps with the Joins http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995212/technique-for-dynamically-adding-a-join-to-a-linq-query I don't tried it yet but that should be the Solution. @Aron